# Can Xarray's open_mfdataset() function work with variable number of files in the nested structure?

Tags: python, dask, netcdf, python-xarray

I am attempting to use Xarray's open_mfdataset() function to open a large number of spatiotemporal files. However, some levels of the hierarchy have different numbers of files even though they result in the same dimensions.

Imagine the file structure that I want to process looks like this:

```
[
    [r1_2000_2050.nc, r1_2050_2100.nc],
    [r2_2000_2025.nc, r2_2025_2050.nc, r2_2050_2100.nc]
]
```

All of the dimensions do match, the spatial dimensions are the same and though the second sublist has more files, the temporal dimensions still run from 2000-2100. I have confirmed that I can combine these files through a manual series of xarray merges and concats but I want to take advantage of open_mfdataset's parallel loading and chunking structure so that I don't load everything into memory.

When I try to load this structure with:

`xr.open_mfdataset(nested_paths, combine='nested', concat_dim=['realization', 'time'])`

I get this error:
`ValueError: The supplied objects do not form a hypercube because sub-lists do not have consistent lengths along dimension0`

If this is possible to do with xarray, that would be extremely beneficial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Xarray doesn't currently support this. (I don't think you could even use Kerchunk to get around this, because it would imply "ragged"-length chunks.)

The reason xarray doesn't support this is because it would break the symmetry between dimensions. In your example concatenating along `'time'` then along `'realization'` would be well-defined, but concatenating along `'realization'` then `'time'` would have a dimension mismatch. For the cases that `combine` supports right now, we can guarantee that either order would work.

We could perhaps imagine relaxing this constraint in xarray, so that `combine='nested'` would succeed in this case if `dim=['time', 'realization']`, but fail if `dim=['realization', 'time']`.

If this is something you would like to see in xarray then you are welcome to help contribute it as a new feature :) But it's not something we are likely to prioritize implementing soon. (If you want to try implementing it I would start by [disabling the exceptions here](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/blob/799f12d756f9edf1a40188461cf3833a0788af82/xarray/core/combine.py#L164) and see how much further through the code it gets.)